# How can I fix 'DB Clusters not supported for engine' when restoring a snapshot on AWS Aurora?

Tags: postgresql, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I'm using the AWS API to restore a cluster snapshot. My code is simple enough, and [follows the `restoreDBClusterFromSnapshot` documentation fairly closely](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/RDS.html):

```
await rds.restoreDBClusterFromSnapshot({
  DBClusterIdentifier: SNAPSHOT_NAME,
  SnapshotIdentifier: `arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:ACCOUNT_ID:cluster-snapshot:SNAPSHOT_NAME`,
  Engine: "postgres",
  EngineMode: 'provisioned',
  EngineVersion: '9.6.12',
  Tags: [
    {
      Key: 'Creator',
      Value: USERNAME
    }
  ]
}).promise()
```

However this call fails with

```
DB Clusters not supported for engine: postgres
```

I know that's not true - we're running a Postgres Cluster in production.

**How can I restore the cluster snapshot?**

Comment: Person asking to close - why? If you need any information I'm happy to provide it.

Answer (score 1):

The error is a little deceptive - it's not that clusters aren't available for `postgres` engine, is that `postgres` isn't a valid engine name.

The correct name for AWS postgres engine is `aurora-postgresql`. I wasn't able to find any mention of this in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/RDS.html) however:

1. Running `rds.describeDBClusters()` on the existing cluster made through the Management Console shows the Engine as `aurora-postgresql`.
2. The TypeScript info for `createDBInstance()` mentions:

> Valid Values: aurora (for MySQL 5.6-compatible Aurora) aurora-mysql (for MySQL 5.7-compatible Aurora) aurora-postgresql mariadb mysql oracle-ee oracle-se2 oracle-se1 oracle-se postgres sqlserver-ee sqlserver-se sqlserver-ex sqlserver-web

```
await rds.restoreDBClusterFromSnapshot({
  DBClusterIdentifier: SNAPSHOT_NAME,
  SnapshotIdentifier: `arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:ID_NUMBER:cluster-snapshot:${SNAPSHOT_NAME}`,
  Engine: "aurora-postgresql",
  EngineMode: 'provisioned',
  EngineVersion: '9.6.12',
  Tags: [
    {
      Key: 'Creator',
      Value: USERNAME
    }
  ]
}).promise()
```